# How to localize to chinese in wso2 admin portal

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I got apim-4.1.0.zip and deployed on my vm，there were 3 portals:

```
[1] https://localhost:9443/publisher
[2] https://localhost:9443/devportal
[3] https://localhost:9443/admin
```

How to translate admin portal to Chinese with correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows.

1. Identify the two-letter locale code for the language that you want to add to the Admin Portal.

   The locale code for the Chinese language is zh.
2. Make a copy of the en.json file and rename it based on the locale code.

   Rename the copy of the <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin/site/public/locales/en.json file to zh.json.
3. Change all the values that correspond to the key-value pairs to the language that you want to add to the Admin Portal.

More information can be found in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/adding-internationalization/